# Optimising memory management for php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, memory-management

I have a table with around 100000 records ,the structure is shown below

```
id  | name    | desc   | length   | breadth | -------------|remark  //upt o 56 fields
1     FRT-100  -desc-       10      10                      remarking
----------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

what iam doing this is using a cronjob(Gearman) to write all these data to a csv ,my code is given below

```
        <?php 
      set_time_limit (0);
     ini_set("memory_limit","2048M");
        //get the total count of records,so that we can loop it in small chunks
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tablename WHERE company_id = $companyid";

            $result = $link->query($query);
            $count = 0;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $count = $row["cnt"];
            }
            if ($count > 1000) {
                $loop = ceil($count / 1000);
            } else {
                $loop = 1;
            }


        // im going to write it in small chunks of 1000's each time to avoid time out

            for ($ii = 1; $ii <= $loop; $ii++) { 

                if ($ii == 1) {
                    $s = 1;
                } else {
                    $s = floatval(($ii * 1000) - 1000);
                }

                $q = "SELECT * FROM datas WHERE group_company_id = $companyid  LIMIT 1000 OFFSET $s";
                $r = $link->query($q);       

        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
                    //my csv writing will be done here and its working fine for records up to 10,000 ~ 12,000 after than memory exhaustion occours
        }
}
    ?>
```

I strongly suspects something can be optimised in the offset function of mysql .Can someone show me a better way to optimise it ? open to any suggestions (CRON,third party libraries ..etc)

Comment: `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {` --- why do you need a loop here?

Comment: @zerkms to get the count of how many records ..since its a single row..yes you are right

Comment: @zerkms can you put some light on the limit,offset issue

Comment: @zerkms `$count = $row[0]["cnt"];` like this

Comment: `$count = $row["cnt"];`

Comment: Are you actually having memory problems, or do you just think you'll be having them? 100k rows isn't very much. Also, the MySQL wire protocol doesn't fetch the entire resultset until you ask for it, so you don't need to page your results...that's just resulting in more queries going to the server with no benefit to you.

Comment: yes im getting time out csv is generating upto 12,000 records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and avoid storing everything in memory at once, instead load each row, then write out result one row at a time.

```
<?php
$q = "SELECT * FROM datas";
$r = $link->query($q);       
$fp = fopen("out.csv","w+"); 
// Or you could just set the headers for content type, and echo the output
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
  fwrite($fp, implode(",",$row2)."\n");
}
fclose($fp);
```

This should solve the issue, nothing is being stored in memory.

Comment: This is actually not 100% accurate, I have since found out that you also need to disable the mysql client from buffering the whole result into memory. To achive this you can use `mysql_unbuffered_query($q)` or if using PDO `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
`